# Cannot boot Ubuntu unless I choose it in in BIOS boot menu after deleting windows partition and reinstalling

Tags: boot, grub2

I was using windows7 and Ubuntu dual boot and things were going fine until I deleted the partition of windows. After reboot the system Ubuntu didn't boot and a grub rescue terminal showed up.

I used a live usb flash drive and reinstalled Ubuntu by erasing everything on the hard disk from scratch, but I am unable to boot Ubuntu automatically; every time I need to press f12 and choose Ubuntu to boot from BIOS setup.

I have run the [boot-info script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EkobeyI6LVRExubTNNNGd3QWc/view?usp=sharing)

When I use Gparted it is throwing this error

```
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
```

Comment: Is Grub installed in MBR, or in Ubuntu partition?

Comment: boot-info says No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

Comment: Then boot with a live CD and install grub from there. The entire process with multiple options are here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing